# Amazon AWS - Sharing file by URL

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use AWS services for saving and retriving files.

I'm trying to generate a url to access and read files / buckets.

I'm doing so by:

```
GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
{
    BucketName = fileDetails.BucketName,
    Key = fileDetails.FileKey,
    Expires = expires
};

result = client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
```

The url generated successfully but when I try to access the file via this url I get the following error:

[image: Access Denied error message]

I think I should grant public permission for this file.
Is someone know what should I do to share a file by url with public permission?

There is no any mention about public permission in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-dot-net-sdk.html).

Comment: It's saying the link has expired. What did you set the `expires` value to?

Comment: I set the Expires value to: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30); @MarkB

Comment: is your client pointing to the right region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you're doing to set the value for `expires` is not working as you expect.

The link has expired.

This error message should be interpreted at face value.

The documentation does not mention this fact (as far as I am aware), but the expiration of pre-signed URLs is verified *before* authentication or authorization checks are done.  There's no point in further validation for a link that can't work because it's expired.

Check the `Expires=` or `X-Amz-Expires=` value in the query string.

`Expires` is the expiration time relative to the unix epoch, or `X-Amz-Expires` is the time, in seconds past `X-Amz-Date`, until the link expiration.  Only one of these will be present (Signature V2 vs. V4 difference).

Note also that once you discover the problem, you can't simply modify the expiration time expressed in the URL to make the value different and then use it -- any kind of tampering with the signed URL will invalidate the signature (by design).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the credentials you are using on your client are tied to a user that has the AmazonS3FullAccess policy attached to it (or a group it belongs to).

Comment: The error is pretty clear, and this answer suggests looking at settings that won't be relevant.  **The signed URL has expired**.  This condition is evaluated before the signature is even validated, and this error will be thrown regardless of whether you are authorized to download the object or not.

Comment: I ran into the exact same error and that's what resolved it. AWS error can be cryptic some times.

Comment: what resolved it?  i have the same error, My app and creating presigned URLs works on one AWS instance, but doesn't work on another !!  (that's the same WAR app)